# Access violation writing location when deleting a matrix

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am writing a program to perform a set of numeric methods. To do this I need to create matrices of arbitrary size and throw them between functions. Obviously if I don't clean up the creates matrices after they're used I get pretty major memory leaks.

```
double** MatrixInitialize(int m, int n)//generates a A[m][n] matrix
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    double** B = new double*[m];
    for (m = 0; m < n; m++)
    {
            B[m] = new double[n];
    }
    for (j = 0;j<m;j++)
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                    B[i][j] = 0;
            }
    return(B);
}

int main()
{
    double** MatrixA;
    MatrixA=MatrixInitialize(2,2) 
    //Some manipulation on MatrixA is done here
    delete[] MatrixA[0]; delete[] MatrixA[1]; delete[] MatrixA; 
    return 0;
}
```

As soon as the delete[] lines are called I get the access violation message thrown and have to break. Is there some other procedure I have to go through the delete these pointers?

Comment: Note: You are modifying a function argument in `for (m = 0; m < n; m++)`

Comment: Besides the logical error, there is no issue here. The sample does not show the actual problem.

Comment: @Dieter This is effectively all my program is doing. I create 2 Matrices, perform a loop doing manipulation on their entries, then want to delete them at the end of the loop. I found that if I did
    MatrixA=NULL;
    delete[] MatrixA;
then it would run, but I could not do the same for the pointers MatrixA[0] and MatrixA[1] and the memory would still leak

Comment: `//Some manipulation on MatrixA is done here`. The blatant logical error Dieter pointed out is bad (think what happens when you try a 2x3 matrix for example), You need to post the code. Setting a pointer to NULL *before* deleting it is pointless, and in all cases but an original NULL value, a blatant memory leak. Post the *real* code; *all of it*.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xCah0vmN

There you go. Infact if I set the pointers to NULL then delete them it seems to not actually leak any memory and runs just fine.

Note the 
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <nag.h>
    #include <nagf07.h>
Are includes for the NAG C Library of numeric methods and are only used in the NRMMatrixCalculation subroutine to solve a set of linear equations.

Answer (score 0):

Let the language work for you

```
int main()
{
    int ysize = 10;
    int xsize = 5;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> B(ysize, std::vector<double>(xsize, 0));

    for (int y = 0; y < ysize; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < xsize; x++)
        {
            B[y][x] = 1.23;
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < ysize; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < xsize; x++)
        {
            std::cout << B[y][x] << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

http://ideone.com/QSoR5M

Comment: Does this not just do the same thing my MatrixInitialization function was doing?

Comment: Yes but it won't leak memory or cause access violation :)

Comment: Even when used inside a loop? I in fact have a loop that calls the function I listed as int main here and in the manipulation I commented out I need to send the MatrixA to another function. Will this method allow me to do that without leaking memory when called multiple times?

Comment: @MikePegg Put a code sample on ideone and I will tell you